# In the autoregressive model AR(p). Why $\mathbb{E}[X_{t}Z_{t}] =\operatorname{Var}[Z_{t}] $?

Tags: statistics, time-series

In the [Autoregressive model](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model) AR(p), of time series, where $X_t=\sum_{i=1}^{p}\phi_{i}X_{t-i}+ Z_{t}$ (Where $Z_t$ is the white noise, $\phi_k$ are constants and $X_t$ random variables) Why is that expected value equal to the variance of $Z_{t}$? Is it related to the fact that we can write the model as a MA($\infty$)? I think that this is obvious because I can't find the explanation. Sorry for asking but I can't stop thinking about it

Comment: what is $X_t$ ?

Comment: @Surb I just provided the full context. Thanks for the observation.

Comment: What is $\varphi _i$ ?

Comment: @Surb Each $\phi_i$ is just a constant, while the $X_k$ are random variables.

Comment: There are several white noise. Please gives the precise definition of what you call white noise.